# Perl Regex Remove Hyphen but Ignore Specific Hyphenated words

Tags: regex, perl, strip

I have a perl regex which converts hyphens to spaces eg:-

```
$string =~ s/-/ /g;
```

I need to modify this to ignore specific hyphenated phrases and not replace the hyphen e.g. in a string like this:

```
"use-either-dvi-d-or-dvi-i"
```

I wish to NOT replace the hyphen in dvi-d and dvi-i so it reads:

```
"use either dvi-d or dvi-i"
```

I have tried various negative look ahead matches but failed miserably.

Comment: What have you tried? Are `dvi-i` and `dvi-d` the only phrases you want to exclude? Or is there a "whitelist" of them?

Comment: Actually a white list may be better as there may be other hyphanated terms I need to keep

Answer (score 4):

You can use this PCRE regex with verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to skip certain words from your match:

```
dvi-[id](*SKIP)(*F)|-
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG1vK5/3)

This will skip words `dvi-i` and `dvi-d` for splitting due to use of `(*SKIP)(*F)`.

For your code:

```
$string =~ s/dvi-[id](*SKIP)(*F)|-/ /g;
```

[Perl Code Demo](http://ideone.com/ecCSFb)

---

There is an **alternate lookarounds based solution** as well:

```
/(?<!dvi)-|-(?![di])/
```

Which basically means match hyphen if it is not preceded by `dvi` OR if it is not followed by `d` or `i`, thus making sure to not match `-` when we have `dvi` on LHS and `[di]` on RHS.

Perl code:

```
$string =~ s/(?<!dvi)-|-(?![di])/ /g;
```

[Perl Code Demo 2](http://ideone.com/7LNnda)

Comment: your regEX demo output(**use either`-`dvi-d or-dvi-i**) is not as expected as desired output .

Comment: I don't think I can use (*SKIP) in perl, it doesn't like it?

Comment: It definitely works in `perl`, [here is a working perl demo](http://ideone.com/ecCSFb)

Comment: I've also added a lookaround based solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string =~ s/(?<!dvi)-(?![id])|(?<=dvi)-(?![id])|(?<!dvi)-(?=[id])/ /g;
```

While using just `(?<!dvi)-(?![id])` you will exclude also `dvi-x` or `x-i`, where `x` can be any character.

Comment: what is this? why are you using alternation?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: Maybe not `i-i`, you can't know it.

Comment: OP says that `I wish to NOT replace the hyphen in dvi-d and dvi-i `..why are you thinking about string `i-i`?

Comment: Exactly, he is talking about excluding only `dvi-d` and `dvi-i` from the match.

Comment: so why the alternation..first condition of yours `(?<!dvi)-(?![id])` is sufficient for that

Comment: I've already explained it. With just `(?<!dvi)-(?![id])` you exclude even something that is not requested to be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I tried $phrase =~ s/(?<!dvi)-(?![id])/ /g; but it returned use either-dvi-d or-dvi-i it didn't remove the hyphen before the word dvi??

Comment: Then I tried  this one, s/(?<!dvi)-(?![id])|dvi-(?![id])|(?<!dvi)-[id]/ /g; and it returned use either vi-d or vi-i, lost the d from dvi

Comment: It is not just slow it is repeating `dvi` 3 times in regex

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you could get a simple and straightforward regex solution to this. However, you could try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %whitelist = map { $_ => 1 } qw( dvi-d dvi-i );

my $string = 'use-either-dvi-d-or-dvi-i';

while ( $string =~ m{ ( [^-]+ ) ( - ) ( [^-]+ ) }gx ) {
    my $segment = substr($string, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]);
    unless ( $whitelist{ $segment } ) {
        substr( $string, $-[2], 1, ' ');
    }
    pos( $string ) = $-[ 3 ];
}

print $string, "\n";
```

The `@-` array contains the starting offsets of matched groups, and the `@+` array contains the ends offsets. In both cases, element `0` refers to the whole match.

I had to resort to something like this [because of how `\G` works](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions):

> Note also that `s///` will refuse to overwrite part of a substitution that has already been replaced; so for example this will stop after the first iteration, rather than iterating its way backwards through the string:
>
> ```
>    $_ = "123456789";
>    pos = 6;
>    s/.(?=.\G)/X/g;
>    print;     # prints 1234X6789, not XXXXX6789
> ```

Maybe @tchrist can figure out how to bend various assertions to his will.

Answer (score -2):

we can ignore specific words using **negative Look-ahead** and **negative Look-behind**

Example :

```
(?!pattern)
is a negative look-ahead assertion
```

in your case the pattern is

```
$string =~ s/(?<!dvi)-(?<![id])/ /g;
```

output :

```
use either dvi-d or dvi-i
```

Reference : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't split on `dvi-abc`

Comment: addition of `\+` will solve your concern. Earlier pattern for the user example only.

Comment: Escaped `\+` after `\w` matches a literal `+`

Comment: There are lots of different way to solve this kind of problem . For example `[0-9,a-z,A-Z]\+` instead of `\w\+` will also work.

Comment: still trying to figure out what is  wrong with my code and why community people give negative feedback. It actually demotivate me to contribute.

Comment: `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind, not a lookahead.  It will always succeed, because `-` is not a word character.  But `(?!\w)` is wrong too, because the OP only cares about `dvi-i` and `dvi-d`, **not** `dvi-x` or `dvi-abc` or `dvi-123`.  Also, the "one or more" quantifier is `+`, not `\+`, and the commas in `[0-9,a-z,A-Z]` are just literal commas.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Thanks a lot for your feedback .I have updated my code.